# Why does my image plane's alpha keep revealing itself, depending on the camera's position in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, image-sequence

I was in 3.4, I have a number of sprites.

To create them, I imported an image sequence (jpg) as a plane.

Then I attached another black and white image sequence (jpgs) as an alpha matte.

Up high you can't see the problem.

Move the camera lower and suddenly the alpha channel (black pixels) is revealed in peculiar ways.

Never had this happen before.

So I updated to 3.6.5 Same problem.

I tried every possible setting in the material menu and nothing changed this.

It happens in CPU rendering also. Doesn't happen in EEVEE.

What the heck could this be?

[image: up high]
[image: down low]
[Video of the problem**](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/17gfqe4/alpha_keeps_revealing_itself_depending_on_the/)

Comment: Do you have enough [max transmission bounces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/3.6/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html#bpy-types-cyclesrendersettings-transmission-bounces) ?